# Adding elements with jQuery messes up positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, alignment

I've been doing some web stuff with jQuery and css, and came across a problem, which I'm unable to find a solution to. I've written a code, where using jQuery, I get data from server and according to that data I add new elements. The elements have a lot of absolute positioning in them, and it messes up whenever I add them via jQuery.
My code is here:

```
function output(progress, data) {
    $("#lookup .bar").css('width', (100/3*progress) + '%');
    if (progress === 3) {
        $("#lookup div.container").html(data);
        $('#lookup').css("text-align", "left");
    }
}
```

Basicly, I just remove the progress bar, and set my text-align to left, because of otherwise even more messed up aligning, this is the only workaround I found... The problem I'm having looks like this: [image]

Although normally, it should look like this: [image]

The strange thing is that the problem fixes itself whenever I refresh styling, for example with firebug, I would just delete some padding, then restore it, and the problem is gone... I feel that it has to do something with jQuery part. I'm pretty sure styling is fine, but if you need me to paste a code here, just ask, and I'll update the post.

UPDATE: Live preview on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/awomen/5/
I know the code is ugly ;)

Comment: Does the same thing happen in all browsers? It's going to be very hard for anybody to answer without seeing the actual markup. If you could reproduce the problem with a jsbin or jsfiddle, that'd be even better.

Comment: I'll see what I can do about reproducing the problem. Tried in chrome, there's no problem there.

Comment: Live preview of the problem: http://jsbin.com/awomen/5/

Comment: Maybe you have some CSS hierarchy problem? I mean, when using a CSS selector, you could have set a "path" to apply the styles. Once you've added another element, this "path" can be broken. ie: `div p a {}`.